# Matlab Installation in Ubuntu

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, sudo

When I try to install Matlab 2011a, I get an error like this.

> /tmp/mathworks_3203/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: Permission denied

I searched internet, but what I found is to become root. I tried becoming root as

> sudo su

However, result did not change. I guess, it is related somehow with superuser and privileges stuff, but nothing worked for me, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit or 64-bit installation of Ubuntu? In what form did you get Matlab (e.g. a CD? a zip? how did you download it, copy the files, extract it?)

Comment: Please note that `sudo -s` is a nicer way to start a root shell than `sudo su`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure the file /jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java (inside your original matlab installation folder) is chmod 755.

Comment: I put the folder, it still gives the same error.

Comment: not the '/tmp/mathworks_3203/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java' file, but the corresponding file in your original matlab installation folder.

Comment: I put the corresponding file.

Comment: @Ares, what does it mean to "put" a folder or file? Give commands and `ls -l` output.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Apparently a problem related to extracting the information from the ISO (I cannot explain how):
http://www.mathworks.se/support/solutions/en/data/1-DHWZAO/

I solved it by installing Furius Iso Mount and mounting the .iso instead of extracting its contents. Then sudo-run the install script as usual. Good luck!